# Is it possible to use boost::asio with DTLS?

Tags: boost-asio, dtls

I think the title says most of it, but I am also interested in understanding what it takes to get DTLS support into asio if there is no existing solution

Comment: I was searching for `boost asio dtls` and came across this question and https://github.com/ging/licode/tree/master/erizo/src/erizo/dtls as a potential answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIO itself does not support DTLS but there is a GitHub library [asio_dtls](https://github.com/sdamm/asio_dtls) which has added support (work-in-progress) into ASIO.

It was [submitted](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/pull/129) to be added into ASIO but the author of ASIO hasn't been accepting new features into ASIO for awhile, most likely because of his efforts to submit ASIO into the C++ standard is taking up all of his spare time.

Comment: Botan also offers a Boost ASIO-compatible wrapper that acts like boost::asio::ssl_stream, which supports DTLS: https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/api_ref/tls.html#tls-asio-stream